# Google docs, speadsheet, how to make one column to the sum of others

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

How do i make a column the sum of others, so for example i want to make what appears in column F for every row the sum of A-E.
I suppose that i am asking is there a wildcard character to indicate the current row

ie something like =sum(A*:E*)

Comment: A excel sheet can go all the way up to 99999999 rows. Do you really want a * ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "copy down" a formula and the references will change automatically, so if you use this formula in F2

`=SUM(A2:E2)`

then you can copy that down the column and the references will update to match each row.

Copying the formula down works similar in Google docs to excel. If you put the cursor on the bottom right of the cell [containing first formula] you can hold down left mouse and drag down as far as you need........or you can simply double-click left mouse and the formula will populate as far down the column as you have continuous data in the adjacent column

Comment: boom done, cheers